# Open to suggestions for improving this basic jQuery

Tags: jquery

I've been playing with jQuery today, and I want to know if I can improve this. I noticed it is a bit slow and not as smooth too. Anyone know why?

Test - http://twomuchwork.com/playground/

My jQuery

/* View Toggle */

```
$(function(){
 $("#hide-top").toggle( 
  function() {
   $("#logo").fadeTo(1000,0,function(){
    $("#logo").animate({'height':'0'},'fast', function(){
     $("#logo").css("display", "none");
     $("#content").animate({'height':'86%'},'400');
     $("#hide-top").html('Show Top');
    });
   });
  },
  function() {
   $("#content").animate({'height':'70%'},'400', function(){
    $("#logo").animate({'height':'80px'},'fast');
    $("#logo").fadeTo(1000,1);
    $("#hide-top").html('Hide Top');
   });
 });

 $("#hide-right").toggle( 
  function() {
   $("#sidebar ul").fadeTo(1000,0,function(){
    $("#content").animate({'width':'96%'},'fast');
    $("#nav-bg").animate({'width':'96%'},'fast');
    $("#nav-bg").animate({'width':'96%'},'fast');
    $("#hide-right").html('Show Right');
   });
  },
  function() {
   $("#content").animate({'width':'77%'},'fast', function(){
    $("#nav-bg").animate({'width':'76%'},'fast');
    $("#sidebar ul").fadeTo(1000,1);
    $("#hide-right").html('Hide Right');
   });
  }
 );
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of things:

**Cache your jQuery objects.** Each time you do `$('selector')` it creates a new jQuery object from that selector, which is a very expensive operation. Caching commonly used jQuery objects like this:

```
var logo = $('#logo');
var nav_bg = $('#nav_bg');
```

**Chain as much as possible.** Similarly, chaining makes your code cleaner and more expressive, as well as having to avoid calling the jQuery function repeatedly.

```
$("#logo").animate({'height':'80px'},'fast').fadeTo(1000,1);
```

**Use built in functions.** Since jQuery already has them, why not use them? Using these also makes the code more readable.

```
// Your's
$("#logo").css("display", "none").fadeTo(1000,1);

// jQuery's
$('#logo').hide().fadeIn(1000);
```

And this last one really depends on what you're doing this for, but **don't hard code numbers into the script.** Put them in variables so that you can change them as necessarily, instead of having to find-and-replace every one of the same values when you need them change.

Comment: +1 - I am going to put variables for the percentages right now.

Comment: I only have 1 occurrence of most of the hard coded numbers. Should I really create a variable for each?

Comment: Is there a way to revert to the original width/height, so I do not have to hard code those numbers in the toggle?

Comment: @Doug Not really, if you're lazy ;) but using variables keeps the script tidy and all of the numbers in one place. Alternatively, grab the original width using the `css` function, then use that instead.